# Setting frame dose not working in OS7

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I am trying to set the frame of my superview when presenting a view, the code i used is

```
navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
navigationController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(32, 20, 1024-(32*2), 748);
[[self navigationController] presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
```

the code was working fine in OS6. but when come to OS7 its not working.

Answer (score 2):

This method has been deprecated in iOS 7.

```
- (void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController animated:(BOOL)animated NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 6_0);
```

Use the following :

```
- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated: (BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
```

Comment: That method has been deprecated, but it still works. And presenting the view controller isn't the problem, as I understand it, it is modifying the frame.

Comment: Presentation is oky.., the problem is with setting frame. I need little more with than the standard width.

Answer (score 1):

If it was working in iOS 6 it was by chance. You are depending on the private view hierarchy used by iOS when presenting modal view controllers, and you've just found out why this is a bad idea. It can, and does, change without warning or documentation. See also, the view hierarchy of a UITableView between iOS 6 and 7.

If you want to make your own style of presented view controller it is safest to write it yourself from scratch rather than hijack one of the existing ones. Try using the custom style of presentation and writing a [transition delegate](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions/).

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found a solution.,

```
BOOL ios7 = [UIDeviceHardware isOS7Device];
if(ios7){
    navigationController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
}
```

Now it works fine. :)